# Create an index that restarts in the beginning of each year

Tags: list, office-365, power-automate, indexed-column

I have never worked with power automate or sharepoint lists in the past. We have a test request system that has a unique identifier of the following format: "PTL"-YEAR-Index. PTL is a constant string, year is a integer with the last two numbers, and index is an autoincrementing index that resets every year. For example, the 17th test request in 2021 would be PTL21-0017. I know how to get the PTL21- part, but I am stuck on how to get an autoincrementing index that restarts every year. Could someone provide a detailed guide on how to do this, with the understanding that I have never worked in either Sharepoint lists or power automate in the past. I am asking for a lot, but I would be extremely grateful! I have found some sources explaining it, but I haven't been able to completely follow any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a column in your list called "Year" to store the year value (which will be used for filtering).
In Power Automate, I hope you're using the "When an item is created" trigger. Add an action to get items from same list and put the query filter given below-

```
Year eq triggerBody()?['Year']
```

Now, you'll get all the existing items for the same year in this action result. Now, Update your item's column next by -

```
"PLR" + length(value(Get_items))
```

This will help you in indexing items according to the year.